# The Shape A Square Wheel Makes Rolling in a circle

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, parametric

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjQax.png)

I've watched a few videos on how square wheels can roll on catenary roads. I've watched [Morphocular's Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWWgGk9JU0E&t=1055s) about rolling a square wheel around an object, but I was wondering what the path would be if the solution was on the outside instead of the inside. I tried to do the calculus, but never ended up getting it right. The image I linked is just a circular pattern of a straight line path, it is just to show what I want. I've found the calculus quite difficult if anyone can lend me a hand. I believe parametric polar coordinates are the way to go, but I am also having trouble just graphing anything in that manner. Lastly, I am aware that different radius' of the squares path, and different square sizes result in 10 'bumps' that evenly fit with any square size/path radius. If anyone could help with this difficult problem, that would be amazing! Thanks.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you are after. Are wanting the center of the square to describe a circle as it rolls along? Or is there some other criterion you are after?